# RegEx replace URL with link (if not exist) and not include if . ! , at the end (period, exclamation point, comma)

Tags: php, regex, regex-group

I've come up with this code to replace URLs in a string with an HTML link wrapped around them (when one does not already exist), how can I omit the period, when the URL is followed by a period and a space `http://google.com. Hello`?

For example, this code:

```
$s = 'Please visit http://google.com. Then return to our site.';
$r = preg_replace('"<a[^>]+>.+?</a>(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\b(?:https?)://\S+"', '<a href="$0">$0</a>', $s);
echo $r;
```

Produces this output:

```
Please visit <a href="http://google.com.">http://google.com.</a> Then return to our site.
```

Playground:
https://glot.io/snippets/g6nx6ub5yl

It works fine with all other URLs I just can't for the life of me figure out how to end capture if followed by a period and space (`.` ), a comma, exclamation point, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved this by modifying the actual regex for match from `\b(?:https?)://\S+` to `(https?:\/\/\S+?)(?=[.,!?]?(\s|$))`

Thanks to this post:
[Find a URL with RegEx without finding the value after it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14342875/find-a-url-with-regex-without-finding-the-value-after-it)

For reference, here's a PHP function that will replace all URLs and emails with links, only if they do not exist already, and exclude/omit punctuation:

```
function replace_links( $content ){
    $content = preg_replace('"<a[^>]+>.+?</a>(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|(https?:\/\/\S+?)(?=[.,!?]?(\s|$))"', '<a href="$0">$0</a>', $content);
    $content = preg_replace('"<a[^>]+>.+?</a>(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|(\S+@\S+\.\S+?)(?=[.,!?]?(\s|$))"', '<a href="mailto:$0">$0</a>', $content);
    return $content;
}
```

I'll keep this gist updated if bugs/issues come up:
https://gist.github.com/tripflex/0cc930c2afe5f4c73f2aed61cedf95d0